# How to rewrite a CSS @import statement

Tags: html, css

I have below css code in my app and i need to rewrite it with out using import.

I understand that it is first checking if IE is version 6, if yes it imports certain CSS if not just empty string.

Is import really necessary here? I am guessing if i were to just write this at the end of all css files this will get priority.

```
@import "javascript:(/msie 6/gi.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? 'table.menu tr.highlight td.icon img { filter: none !important; margin-left: 1px !important; margin-right: 3px !important; margin-top: 1px !important; margin-bottom: 3px !important;)' : ''";
```

Comment: It's probably better to create a completely different stylesheet containing IE6-only styles, and then include it with [conditional comments](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/) in your HTML file. Also, ask yourself if you *really* need to still support IE6. It's an ancient browser, and [not many people use it anymore](http://www.ie6countdown.com/). It's a different story if you have a client requiring its use, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .css file, you can 'hack' to scope ie6 only by adding a ( * html ) before a declaration.

IE-6 ONLY

```
* html .selector { 
    /* this will apply to ie6 only */
}
```

You can also use the underscore hack but this will cause validation errors in your CSS file. For reference, here’s an example :

```
.selector {
    margin:0;
    _margin-left:5px; /* only IE6 */
}
```

So you can try :

```
* html table.menu tr.highlight td.icon img {
    filter: none !important;
    margin-left: 1px !important;
    margin-right: 3px !important;
    margin-top: 1px !important;
    margin-bottom: 3px !important;
}
```

If you need more infos about .css hacks to target IE, you can read [some examples here](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/).

> ```
> IE-6 ONLY
> * html #div { 
>     height: 300px;
> }
>
> IE-7 ONLY
> *+html #div { 
>     height: 300px;
> }
>
> IE-8 ONLY
> #div {
>   height: 300px\0/;
> }
>
> IE-7 & IE-8
> #div {
>   height: 300px\9;
> }
>
> NON IE-7 ONLY:
> #div {
>    _height: 300px;
> }
>
> Hide from IE 6 and LOWER:
> #div {
>    height/**/: 300px;
> }
>
> html > body #div {
>       height: 300px;
> }
> ```

If you want to 'replace' the @import with conditional technique, then, user [PeterVR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1340674/petervr) answer is more to the point using a Microsoft conditional comment in the header part of your html document.

Answer (score 6):

Personally I would put the IE6 styles in a separate stylesheet, and and use conditional comments in the head of my HTML to include it:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

The technique is very well explained here: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

As you will notice this technique works for most other versions of IE as well. I prefer this technique to the inline hacks as described by @Milkywayspatterns cause it keeps your code a lot cleaner, more readable, and easier to maintain. Also it prevents the IE only css from getting loaded by real browsers. They will ignore the code (as they should, they are comments after all) and only IE users will have to wait for the extra bytes to load...

And I do not envy you for still having to support IE6!

Comment: I agree just mostly because of the last line.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional comments in the `head` element rather than import in the CSS. This will isolate to IE 6 only:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
    <style type="text/css">
        table.menu tr.highlight td.icon img { 
            filter: none !important; 
            margin-left: 1px !important; 
            margin-right: 3px !important;
            margin-top: 1px !important; 
            margin-bottom: 3px !important;
        }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

In this situation however, it's probably better to create a dedicated IE6 stylesheet and add that in. Either way will work.